# How to retrieve an URL from an API response object from Cloudinary JAVA

Tags: cloudinary

i am developing a web app using Java. I deployed my app to Heroku. In Heroku i am using an Add-on called Cloudinary to store my pictures in cloud, and retrieve them when needed. I am using the search api to retrieve a picture from the cloudinary cloud, but i can't manage to access the url from the response api. Below is my Java code:

```
String nameOfPicture = nameOfRecipe;
    Cloudinary cloudinary = null;
    try {
        cloudinary = new Cloudinary(String.valueOf(new URI(System.getenv("CLOUDINARY_URL"))));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    String imgUrl = null;
    try {
        ApiResponse result = cloudinary.search()
                .expression(nameOfPicture)
                .maxResults(10)
                .execute();
        System.out.println(result.get("resources"));
        System.out.println(result.get("url"));
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

If i System.out.println(result.get("resources")) i can see there is a response from cloudinary like this:

```
[{
        aspect_ratio = 1.77778,
        access_control = null,
        format = jpg,
        resource_type = image,
        secure_url = https: //res.cloudi nary.com/...../POULTRY/ACAPULCO_CHICKEN.jpg, created_at=2020-12-15T18:12:39+00:00, backup_bytes=0, type=upload, ve rsion=1608055959, access_mode=public, created_by={access_key=..., external_id=......}, url=http://res.cloudinary.com /...../v1608055959/FOOD_IMG/POULTRY/ACAPULCO_CHICKEN.jpg, public_id=FOOD_IMG/POULTRY/ACAPULCO_CHICKEN, uploaded_by={access_key=....... .., external_id=.......}, folder=FOOD_IMG/..., filename=...., pixels=360000, uploaded_at=2020-12-15T18:12:39
            +00: 00,
        bytes = 131330,
        width = 800,
        etag = ce45a927d98e07e1c73bd16030218f96,
        height = 450,
        status = active
    }, {
        aspect_ratio = 0.66667,
        access_control = null,
        format = j pg,
        resource_type = image,
        secure_url = https: //res.cloudinary.com/...../FOOD_IMG/POULTRY/ADOBO_CHICKEN_GINGER.jpg, created_at= 2020-12-15T16:40:52+00:00, backup_bytes=0, type=upload, version=1608050452, access_mode=public, created_by={access_key=....., external_id=.......}, url=http://res.cloudinary.com/hmzve6z5z/image/upload/..../POULTRY/ADOBO_CHICKEN_GINGER.jpg, public_id=FOOD_ IMG/POULTRY/ADOBO_CHICKEN_GINGER, uploaded_by={access_key=...., external_id=......}, folder=FOOD_IMG/POULTRY, filenam e=ADOBO_CHICKEN_GINGER, pixels=960000, uploaded_at=2020-12-15T16:40:52+00:00, bytes=242816, width=800, etag=......d, height=120 0, status=active}]
```

Question is, how can i acces and retrieve the url of the picture from this response ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The response is a JSON object and you can loop over it and grab the secure_url.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = outerObject.getJSONArray("resources");
for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String secure_url=objectInArray.get("secure_url").toString();
}
```